# MySql get transactions that occurred with the current date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am working on an application where I need to get all DB entries what occured within the current day.

So if today is September 5, I need to get all transactions that occurred on that date.

How can I do this in a linq query?

I am storing DateTime.Now() in the db for that entity.

Comment: just from one table or all the tables ? IF one, show us the table structure

Comment: It is just a table called "Entity" that has a "date" data type called Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
var date = new DateTime(2012, 9, 5);
var dateEntities = Entities.Where(e => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(e.Date, date) == 0 )
```

Comment: can I do var date = DateTime.now and still have this function correctly?

Comment: use date = DateTime.Now.Date, if you only want today's date

Comment: One problem is that my Entities is of type Icollection so there is no .Where function avaliable, how can I over come this limitation?

Comment: ICollections implement IEnumerable, which give you access to the [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx).  Are you including the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: yea that was the issue! thank you so much for your help, as you can tell I am new to this LINQ and .net stuff, but I enjoy it very much and am always learning new things!